# Make Entity Framework be case-insensitive

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, string-comparison

Is it possible to set entity framework string comparison case insensitive by default?

If I use

```
string.StartsWith("stringToCompare", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

it works. But when I need to use

```
string.Contains("strigToCompare")
```

it doesn't have an overload.

Comment: SQL is anyway case insensitive and EF is only delegating its queries it SQL, EF does not control case, I think it's your database's collation problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply change the case of both fields to Upper Case:

```
String stringToCompare = "Some String";

string.ToUpper().Contains(stringToCompare.ToUpper())
```

This will make the search case-insensitive by converting all case to upper.  Of course, ToLower() would work as well.

Comment: This would break for the test "Foo" & "Foobar"  . given that foobar contains foo.  This may not be the equality you are looking for.

Comment: The poster is asking for case-insensitivity when using the Contains() function.  The "Foo" & "Foobar" example would return "true" which is the desired result.