# Entity Framework contains clause doesn't find

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, contains

I use contains clause for searching in db table. But if the data has upper case letter and if I search with lower cases, it doesn't find what I search. But it can find when I search with upper case letter. It is the same with lower case searches.

Here is my code:

```
 using (var context = new eTicaretEntity())
  {
    return context.GetActiveProducts().Where(p => p.Name.Contains(name)).ToList();
  }
```

And you can see what I mean is these pics.

It can find with upper case letter.

[image: It can find]

It couldn't find data with lower case letter.
[image]

Comment: If you take a look at this previous question should get you going


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069241/make-entity-framework-be-case-insensitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your database collation is case sensitive, then you'll have to convert both sides of the comparison to upper (or lower) case.

```
using (var context = new eTicaretEntity())
{
    return context.GetActiveProducts()
                  .Where(p => p.Name.ToUpper().Contains(name.ToUpper()))
                  .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your simple solution:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
return context.GetActiveProducts().Where(p => 
          p.Name.IndexOf(name,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0).ToList();
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Will that translate to SQL? I don't think IndexOf has a SQL translation in EF.

Comment: Yes it will translate to sql

Comment: Didn't know about that. Is that new in EF 5? Do you have a reference?